# Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -4

Tags: perl, indexing

I am newbie to perl. My script was running for months together and now it is causing a problem and it wont send an email. The script actually sends 2 different graphs (line and bar) of the total number cases per week and its average.
This is the line that is throwing error.

$graph->set_legend(@week_start_dates[-4..-1]);
Error message-Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -4

Is it something to do with perl where you cannot increase the index on left.(-4,-5) etc.
Any thoughts much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because subroutine parameters are aliases to the actual value, the value has to exist, and while it will create positive indexes if they don't exist, it doesn't lengthen the array to create negative indexes, because that would change the meaning of other indexes that do exist.

You can see this simply with:

```
perl -wle'@x = 1..3; sub{}->(@x[-4..-1])'
Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -4 at -e line 1.
```

So you should figure out why there are less than four week_start_dates.

Or if having less than four week_start_dates is acceptable, you could use the following:

```
@week_start_dates > 4 ? @week_start_dates[-4..-1] : @week_start_dates
```